# Use Dynamic Link inside URL in SFMC passing JobID

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have the following problem, this has been killing me all day today. Even though a read the marketing cloud documentation about AMPscript, I couldn't use dynamic links inside the email that I sent in SFMC.

I am looking for use dynamic links inside the email content like this:

```
="%%=concat("https://www.xxyy.com/busca?fq=H%3A1425&utm_source=", %%jobid%%, "5430J&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=DESPACHO", Format(now(),"dd/MM/yyyy") )=%%"
```

Also, when I sent an email, I didn't get success results and then I got the following results:

> The overlay has failed to load.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing **%%jobid%%**, remove the percentages and write only **jobid** like this:

```
%%=concat("https://www.xxyy.com/busca?fq=H%3A1425&utm_source=", jobid, "5430J&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=DESPACHO", Format(now(),"dd/MM/yyyy") )=%%"
```

With personalization strings used within inline code declaration, you don't need to use the percentages.
     Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Like Omri Brandes already said you need to delete the %% around jobid to make it work.
But there is another thing i would like to point at. You dont use RedirectTo function in your code, which i believe is another mistake in this.

From Omri Brandes Code:

```
%%=concat("https://www.xxyy.com/busca?fq=H%3A1425&utm_source=", jobid, "5430J&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=DESPACHO", Format(now(),"dd/MM/yyyy") )=%%
```

To this code with RedirectTo:

```
%%=RedirectTo(concat("https://www.xxyy.com/busca?fq=H%3A1425&utm_source=", jobid, "5430J&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=DESPACHO", Format(now(),"dd/MM/yyyy") ) )=%%
```

Are you aware that Salesforce Marketing Cloud offers a Web Analytics connector where you do not have to set these values manually for every link but instead can set values in the email properties?

Watch the documentation of [**Web Analytics Connector**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_wa_web_analytics_connector.htm&type=5) for a little bit of info, otherwise please comment on my answer ;)